# How to connect to memcachedb and use API

Tags: python-2.7, libmemcached, memcachedb

I have installed [memcachedb](http://memcachedb.org/) according to the [Memcachedb: The complete guide](http://memcachedb.org/memcachedb-guide-1.0.pdf), and I am able to set and get the key,values using telnet as explained in the guide.

What I really want to do is to set and get the key, value pairs from a python script.

I have the memcachedb running on the Ubuntu machine by following command:

> sudo ./memcachedb -vv -u root -H ~/mcDB/ -N

I read and found out that libmemcached python client can be used to communicate with memcachedb.
So, I am using the following test script

```
import memcache

client=memcache.Client([('localhost',21201)]) # port for memcachedb

print "return value  " + str(client.set("key","value"))

print "get result  " + str(client.get("key"))
```

But it gives the following output:

> return value  0
>
> get result  None

I have also tried replacing localhost with 127.0.0.1, does not work either.

In fact, there is no output by memcachedb (-vv option) on running the python script while there is when I use telnet to set and get.

So how can I connect to memcachedb and execute commands through python (get and set)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So instead of python-memcached, I tried [pylibmc](http://sendapatch.se/projects/pylibmc/) and now that script is working. 
There is probably some problem with python-memcached.

Updated script looks as follows:

```
import pylibmc

client=pylibmc.Client(["127.0.0.1:21201"]) # port for memcachedb

print "return value  " + str(client.set("key","value"))

print "get result  " + str(client.get("key"))
```